# Understanding MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to understand the MVVM pattern. I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial). I am stock at Example 4, framework. Putting the code cause issue for me at least for the observable class. I created a new folder called it HelperClass inside my project and copy and pasted the observable class.

Observable.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Morza.HelperClass
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
        {
            var propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(propertyExpresssion);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Warns the developer if this Object does not have a public property with
        /// the specified name. This method does not exist in a Release build.
        /// </summary>
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public void VerifyPropertyName(String propertyName)
        {
            // verify that the property name matches a real,  
            // public, instance property on this Object.
            if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
            {
                Debug.Fail("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However PropertySupport say it does not exist in the current concept. Morza is the project name.

My second questions:

If I want to implement observable, do I need to implement two ViewModel, where

If I have a person I would do the following

```
Model
  Person

ViewModel
  PersonViewModel
  PersonListViewModel
```

Where PersonListViewModel would have an observable list of PersonViewModel?

Comment: Is `PropertySupport` a Prism feature?  You might need to use Nuget to include Prism in your solution

Comment: This is a good reason not to *start* with a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropertySupport` is not part of .NET. If you are using a framework tutorial, make sure to include that framework in your project.

The standard INotifyPropertyChanged implementation looks like this:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To answer your second question, your whole *view* should have a view model. That view model would then contain your list of `Person` objects. If you want to make separate `Person` model and view model objects, then it would contain a `PersonViewModel` collection instead. This separation is often unnecessary however.

`PersonListViewModel` is very unlikely to be needed. Just by the name, it sounds like a class you do not want to have.